# Spring Security Oauth2 login with custom authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, spring-oauth2

I am using spring boot 3 and spring security 6.

My goal is to implement a login functionality that works with JWT tokens. The login page should have two options:

- Custom login/register form
- Login with Google (OAuth2 login)

**The custom authentication flow works as follows:**

- The user enters their username and password through the login page.
- The username is fetched from the database and the password is checked for a match.
- A JWT token is then generated and returned in the response.
- The client app uses this JWT token for subsequent requests.

**I imagine the login with Google flow should include following steps:**

When I receive authorization code from Google's redirection after the user has granted access, I proceed with the following steps.

- Exchange the authorization code for an access token and verify it.
- Fetch user information from Google.
- Create or fetch the user from the database.
- Generate the same type of JWT token as in the custom authentication flow.
- Add the JWT token to the response and redirect it to my UI app.
- The UI app then handles subsequent requests with the JWT token provided.

After analyzing Spring Security's default functionality, I see that the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter` is responsible for authentication after the authorization server redirects with the code.

it seems that This filter roughly executes the following steps:

- Fetch the original auth request from the session.
- Perform code/token exchange.
- Verify the token.
- Fetch user info from Google.
- Authenticate the user.

So, I understand I need to create a custom version of this filter and implement the steps I've designed for my use case.

However, I see that Spring Security does not allow setting a custom filter for OAuth2 login. It is tightly coupled with `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`. Look at the OAuth2LoginConfigurer class definition here.

`public final class OAuth2LoginConfigurer<B extends HttpSecurityBuilder<B>> extends AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer<B, OAuth2LoginConfigurer<B>, OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter> {`

Do you have any ideas on how I can appropriately implement this functionality?

If my flow doesn't seem right to you, I am open to alternative solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

In OAuth2, login (authorization-code flow) is initiated by the client, with a redirect to authorization server.

Login steps (username / pasword form, MFA, login with Google, etc.) are authorization server business. What you explored in Spring Security OAuth2 client API is called after the user was authenticated on the authorization server.

So, what you are requesting is an authorization server with "login with Google". You can write your own with Spring authorization server project, pick one "from the shelf" like Keycloak or choose between many cloud offers (Auth0, Amazon Cognito, Azure AD, etc...). Almost all have social login features.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working in an Spring boot app where I try to allow my users/customers make login with it's credentials or using google OAuth2 and then return them a JWT token.
So basically what I do is create a class that extends from SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler where I customize the behavior after a successful OAuth2 authentication, in that class I get the information of the authentication (it's a OAuth2User) and I valid if the email that it contain exist in my data base and if it true I continue with the process of create the token.
look the code:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomOAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends 
SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;
    @Autowired
    private TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, 
    ServletException {

        if(authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken){
           OAuth2User oauth2User = ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) 
authentication).getPrincipal();
            Customer customer = customerRepository.
                         findCustomerByEmail(oauth2User.getAttribute("email").toString()).
orElse(null);
            if(customer!=null){
                System.out.println("customer exist");
                String token = jwtService.generateToken(customer);
                //more process you have to do in your logic
                response.getWriter().write(token);
                response.getWriter().flush();

            }else{
                //customer doesn't exist, throw an error or create new one
            }
        }else{
            //error
        }

       }
}
```

And my config class, I add the CustomOAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler class.

```
    .oauth2Login(oauth->{         
oauth.successHandler(customOAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler);
                    oauth.failureHandler(new 
SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/login?error=true"));
                           })
```

That is the way in what I allow my users to make login with it's credentials or using OAuth2 google. I'm using Spring boot 3 and Spring security 6. Maybe that can help you :)